# Close an Extended dialog

Tags: java, android

I have a class

```
public class DialogEx extends Dialog
{
//
}
```

Somewhere out there I can use the `DialogEx` like this

```
DialogEx d=new DialogEx();
d.show();
//d.cancel
```

I don't know how to close the dialogEx when I click its face. I think inside the code of the class `DialogEx` above I should implement an `setOnClickListener` then call the `this.close()` inherited from `Dialog`. Sad but true there is no such a method in the base class. :-(

**My problem is: I need to implement a `close` method inside that DialogEx, I know `dismiss` that I can call from outside the class.**

Comment: d.dismiss() method to dismiss the dialog

Comment: try `d.dismiss();` instead of `d.close()`

Comment: Sad, but you all get me wrong. Please reread my post!

Answer (score 1):

```
final DialogEX dialog = new DialogEX(YourActivity.this);
```

You need lowercase dialog.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   dialog.dismiss();
}
```

Also `AlertDialog.Builder` may be a better choice for you.

You can call [`dismiss`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss%28%29) on the dialog.

Comment: As per official document: 
`Dismiss this dialog, removing it from the screen. This method can be invoked safely from any thread. **Note that you should not override this method** to do cleanup when the dialog is dismissed, instead implement that in onStop().`